# Is it legal to distribute EXEs inside system32 folder with my product

Tags: licensing, windows, software-distribution

I'm developing a product related to printing. To work it properly in all windows versions I need to include few exe (lpr.exe) files from system32 folder. So I need to know it is legal to distribute these exe file with my product.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a question of legality.  Such questions can only be properly answered by lawyers.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. What i need is some guidance from programmers experience. Just curious: is there any forum in stackExchange for this kind of questions?

Answer (score 5):

Ignoring the legality, its a profoundly **bad idea** to install a version of a Windows system exe on other installations running different versions of Windows (both major and minor).  You should look to see if MS has some sort of redistributable package for that program that you can include in your installer to enable the functionality you are looking for, or re-evaluate your current approach to whatever it is you are doing..

Answer (score 3):

The answer is pretty much no.

Those files are Microsoft's, and they have prohibited redistribution.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Any documented note such as?

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya: The license agreement (EULA) that comes with the version of Windows that you are taking the EXEs from.